# JQuery replace all text for element containing string in id

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all elements on the page which have the string 'aggr' as part of their id value. Then I am trying to replace the text 'Sum 'in these elements to 'Total'.

My JQuery is below but doesn't seem to be working....

```
$('TBODY[id*=aggr]').each(function(i){
var aggrHTML = $('TBODY[id*=aggr]');
          var aggrText = aggrHTML.text();
          var newText = aggrText.replace("Sum","Total Holiday Leave")
         aggrHTML.html(newText);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('TBODY[id*=aggr]').each(function(i){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Sum","Total Holiday Leave"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('TBODY[id*=aggr]').each(function(i){
          var aggrText = $(this).text();
          var newText = aggrText.replace("Sum","Total Holiday Leave")
          $(this).html(newText);
});
```

I think that will work.

Basically you it iterates over a set of objects, but you have to use $(this) to get the current object.

I left it the way you had it so you can understand it more.

Comment: it seems to select the right elements and text but some how doesnt replace the text 'Sum' with 'Total Holiday Leave'.  Sarfraz's script does this though... Thanks though