# JQuery replace html element contents if ID begins with prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, innerhtml

I am looking to move or copy the contents of an HTML element. This has been asked before and I can get innerHTML() or Jquery's html() method to work, but I am trying to automate it.

If an element's ID begins with 'rep_', replace the contents of the element after the underscore.

So,

```
<div id="rep_target">
Hello World.
</div>
```

would replace:

```
<div id="target">
Hrm it doesn't seem to work..
</div>​
```

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="rep_"]').html(function() {
        $(this).replaceAll($(this).replace('rep_', ''));
    });
});​
```

-and-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="rep_"]').each(function() {
        $(this).replace('rep_', '').html($(this));
    });
​});​
```

Neither seem to work, however, this does work, only manual:

```
var target = document.getElementById('rep_target').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = target;
```

Related, but this is only text.
[JQuery replace all text for element containing string in id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239444/jquery-replace-all-text-for-element-containing-string-in-id)

Comment: where does the replacement come from? do you want to transfer-replace (transfer an existing content to replace target)? or clone-replace (copy an existing content and replace target)?

Comment: General comments: you are using html wrong in your example: html takes a string, not a function, as an argument.  Similarly you are using replace incorrectly; if you want to change an attribute (any attribute, including "id") you should use attr.  I think the latter confusion comes from misunderstanding what exactly $(foo) returns: it's not the element's ID, nor is it the element itself (or elements).  Instead, it's a wrapper around the element(s), something like [element1, element2, ...], but with extra methods that an array normally wouldn't have.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm a JS noob. I need to take the formatted HTML contents from id="rep_target1" and replace or append the contents of id="target1". Basically, search for all elements that have id="rep_X" then find and replace id="X" there are multiple instances on the page with different X values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two basic options for the first part: replace with an HTML string, or replace with actual elements.

Option #1: HTML

```
$('#target').html($('#rep_target').html());
```

Option #2: Elements

```
$('#target').empty().append($('#rep_target').children());
```

If you have no preference, the latter option is better, as the browser won't have to re-construct all the DOM bits (whenever the browser turns HTML in to elements, it takes work and thus affects performance; option #2 avoids that work by not making the browser create any new elements).

That should cover replacing the insides.  You also want to change the ID of the element, and that has only one way (that I know)

```
var $this = $(this)
$this.attr($this.attr('id').replace('rep_', ''));
```

So, putting it all together, something like:

```
$('[id^="rep_"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    // Get the ID without the "rep_" part
    var nonRepId = $this.attr('id').replace('rep_', '');
    // Clear the nonRep element, then add all of the rep element's children to it
    $('#' + nonRepId).empty().append($this.children());

    // Alternatively you could also do:
    // $('#' + nonRepId).html($this.html());

    // Change the ID
    $this.attr(nonRepId);

    // If you're done with with the repId element, you may want to delete it:
    // $this.remove();
});
```

should do the trick.  Hope that helps.

Comment: As a side note, you may have noticed a pattern here with both the html and attr methods: if you invoke them without arguments, you get the value back, and if you provide an argument, you set that argument as the value.  This pattern applies to lots of other methods in jQuery as well (text, val, etc.)

Comment: This is pretty close, but I need to do option #1 dynamically. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SZUZt/

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer how you can combine the two parts.  I used option #2 in the combined version, because it will perform better, but you can easily substitute option #1 if you prefer.

Comment: You are a Godsend. Thank you so much. I tweaked it just a tad, but this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Get the id using the `attr` method, remove the prefix, create a selector from it, get the HTML code from the element, and return it from the function:

```
$('[id^="rep_"]').html(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  id = id.replace('rep_', '');
  var selector = '#' + id;
  return $(selector).html();
});
```

Or simply:

```
$('[id^="rep_"]').html(function() {
  return $('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('rep_', '')).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From my question, my understanding is that you want to replace the id by removing the re-_ prefix and then change the content of that div. This script will do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items= $('[id^="rep_"]');
    $.each(items,function(){
       var item=$(this);
       var currentid=item.attr("id");
       var newId= currentid.substring(4,currentid.length);
        item.attr("id",newId).html("This does not work");        
        alert("newid : "+newId);
    });    

});
```

Working Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/eh3RL/13/